# URL blocked ( Access-Control-Allow-Origin - Missing Header) while I am trying to get the data from Bluehost to react website app

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, react-native, web-applications

I am creating a website using (react for website) that I wanted to get the data from my server in blueHost using php as a backend and react (JavaScript) as front-end

I have an issue that I am not able to load the data case of my file.php has blocked because of `Access control allow Origin`

any idea how can solve this issue?

here is my code app.js (react)

```
    const getData = async () => {
    fetch(URL,{
      mode:'cors',
      headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3004',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
    'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'x-token'
    }
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => console.log(json.flags))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    .finally(() => console.log(false));
```

}

and here is my file.php

```
 <?php
include 'DBConfig.php';
 
$conn = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, X-Requested-With");

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, true);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
 
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Transactions`";
 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
 
if ($result->num_rows >0) {
 
 
 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 
 $tem = $row;
 
 $json = json_encode($tem);
 
 
 }
} else {
    $json = json_encode("false");

}
 echo $json;
$conn->close();
?>
```

any idea how can I solve this issue?

Comment: So, the error message you are getting back is just, Access control allow Origin ? Or is it simply that you get no data?

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers are server-side only, they shouldn't be part of AJAX/fetch/XHR. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is for POST, but you are using a GET, and then you are later changing it to `Content-type` which is probably also not needed since you aren't sending JSON, either. `Access-Control-Request-Headers` is forbidden in the normal query and is only for preflight `OPTIONS`.

Comment: Where are you trying this code? Where front-end and back-end? I'm asking because I see 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3004', but earlier you wrote that front and back are on blueHost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error is because of run code in local. for fix this. you should add this extension in google chrome. (Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin) then on and off .then on again and test your code.